# Update tycho pom & manifest and commit changes to SVN via Maven

Tags: maven, hudson, pom.xml, tycho, manifest.mf

I'm using a hudson server to create release builds. My goal is to set the new delevopment version to my snapshot, build the release artefact (RCP artifact build with tycho) and commit the new delevopment version to my svn repository.

For this I've set up a step in my hudson job configuration which is calling the following plugin from my build pom

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
 <artifactId>tycho-versions-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>0.19.0</version>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <id>versions</id>
   <phase>validate</phase>
   <goals>
    <goal>set-version</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
    <newVersion>${development.version}</newVersion>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

The plugin is setting the pom and manifest properties correctly so that there is no mismacht between them.

The next step is successful. The release artifact is build.

After this the last step should contain only the commit of the changes, pom and manifest only, to the svn. I've added the scm plugin with goal 'check-in'

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.9.2</version>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <id>commit-versions</id>
   <phase>validate</phase>
   <goals>
    <goal>checkin</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
    <includes>MANIFEST.MF,pom.xml</includes>
    <developerConnectionUrl>scm:svn:svn://ip_and_path<developerConnectionUrl>
    <message>commit from hudson - triggered by release build</message>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

This goal fails because the manifest and pom version do not match in the phase 'validate'. But I've checked the resources on the build server and both, version and qualifier are matching. Has someone an idea? Please ask if my question is not detailed enough.

Comment: So, did you try out the provided answer? If yes, please give feedback, e.g. by accepting the answer that worked, or by adding a comment why it didn't work.

Comment: I'm currently debugging when I've got time. The configuration of my root pom is not used. But this is a problem between hudson and maven.

Answer (score 0):

The [`includes` parameter of the `checkin` goal](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkin-mojo.html#includes) is a comma-separated list of patterns relative the to the root directory. So to check-in the manifest, you need to specify it with its path as

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

or use the pattern

```
**/MANIFEST.MF
```